# Why is command in parentheses (process substitution) no longer working?

Tags: bash

I'm using bash on Ubuntu 16.04. Today I noticed that commands of the form:

```
cmd1 <(cmd2)
```

are giving me the error

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Very similar commands worked a few days ago on the same system, and they work on my other Ubuntu system. Why is this format suddenly not working anymore on this system?

Comment: Are you really using `bash` or have you inadvertently dropped into a different shell?

Comment: @roaima This is really bash. The problem was caused by turning on posix.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that earlier in my session I had run the command

```
set -o posix
```

to get something else working, but process substitution isn't supported in POSIX, so the commands that use it failed.

Doing the following fixed the situation:

```
set +o posix
```

Comment: Note that the behaviour for `cmd1 <(cmd2)` is _unspecified_ by POSIX, not required to give an error, so `bash` didn't have to disable it in `posix` mode. That's different from brace expansion or history expansion which `bash` fails to disable in POSIX mode even though they do conflict with POSIX (that's likely to change though as `bash` is not the only shell that supports those).